# passing object in rpyc fails

Tags: python, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, rpyc

I am trying to pass an object as a paramater using RPyC from the client to the server. But the server is unable to access the object and I receive an AttributeError.

**Server Code:**

```
class AgentService(rpyc.Service):
  def exposed_func(self, obj):
    return obj.name
```

**client code**

```
self._conn = connect(agent_host, agent_port, config = {"allow_public_attrs" : True})
return self._conn.root.func(obj)
```

`returns: AttributeError: cannot access 'name'.`

I am using [RPyC](http://rpyc.sourceforge.net/) services and accoding to the website, this should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: David, Thanks for the edit - looks much more professional...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The config dict needs to be adjusted on the client side and the server side.

The main value to change is `allow_public_attrs : True` if only public variables need to be accessed or `allow_all_attrs : True` if private and protected variables and methods need to be accessed (i.e, those that start with '_').

On the client side, the connection code is written as in the question above and on the server code as follows:

```
server = ThreadedServer(MyService, port = 12345,
                        protocol_config = {"allow_public_attrs" : True})
```

For more information on all the available config options, see:

http://rpyc.sourceforge.net/api/core_protocol.html